# Can't unstick button from textarea

Tags: html, css, forms, media-queries, contact-form

I have a problem with a contact form I'm making. There are two left floating columns with "name" and "email" in one, then "message" in the other. I want my button to be below the two columns and be centered within the form.

My problem is that, when it's less then 50%, the button sticks to the "message". Even though its parent is the form, the button wants to style itself with the "message" column.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/b9rp3Ls4/1/) is a link to my problem in jsfiddle.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
        <div class="column">
            <label for="name">name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            <label for="email">email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
       </div>

        <div class="column">
            <label for="message">message</label>
            <textarea id="message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="bottom-button" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

And my CSS:

```
form {
  padding: 0 5% 0 5%; }
  form .column {
    width: 100%; }
  form label {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #553445;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 2px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px; }
  form input, form textarea {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #553445;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(85, 52, 69, 0.1);
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(85, 52, 69, 0.4);
    outline: none; }
    form input:active, form input:focus, form textarea:active, form textarea:focus {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #fff; }
  form input {
    margin-bottom: 40px; }
  form textarea {
    min-height: 200px;
    resize: none; }

button {
  background: #e85657;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0.5em;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1.05em;
  padding-right: 1.05em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease; }
  button:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #e85657; }
  button:focus {
    outline: none; }
  button a {
    color: inherit; }

#bottom-button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px; }

@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  #ajax-contact .column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%; }
  #ajax-contact textarea {
    min-height: 146px; }
  #ajax-contact #bottom-button {
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: auto; } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button wasn't part of the styled div, `<div class="column">`.

See updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b9rp3Ls4/6/

**EDIT:**  Based on the comment, I've centered it using this resource from the W3C, available here: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

The new JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b9rp3Ls4/7/

It's better to use the same parent if you're trying to center within. Use the margins to put it right in the middle.

Comment: The button is intentionally separate. I'm trying to center it in the form. If that makes sense. After the 30em media query, I'm trying to make it have an auto width and be below the two columns.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I'm on my phone I'll check as soon as i get back